# installing OpenERP 7 on windows 8.1?

Tags: odoo

I have Toshiba Windows 8.1 / and Kaspesky internet security

I want to install OpenERP 7.

When I install the allinone version, I get that the PostgreSQL is already installed in my computer (which it is not). I only get to install the openERP server.

Which is why the ( www.localhost:8069/ ) HTTP 404 NOT FOUND

What can I do?

Comment: Not really a programming question. This is how to work with a vendor's product. You should contact the vendor.

Comment: But I really need help in this ..I tried eveything from REinstalling evrything to installing posgreSQL saparately from openERP

Answer (score 0):

I am using openerp 7 with Windows 8.1 and it's working fine.

Try to clean the windows registry then go to programme files and look for any folder named openerp and delete it.

You should always install openerp and postgreSQL at the same time, don't install any other version of postgre.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: thank you, Yes I tried to delete everything but still no use . That's why I installed openERP 7 and the postgreSQL separatly , it seems that there's still a trace of postgreSQL somewhere that I can't delete ?  or do I have to desactivate Kaspesky internet security ?

Comment: Try to make a system restore and chose the farthest point ( for example 3 months ago ).